# Prometheus Exporters - Building

Tags: build, rabbitmq, gnu-make, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am looking to build project for below given GitHub links. But unable to understand how to get .exe version/build the project which can be used directly.

```
https://github.com/justwatchcom/elasticsearch_exporter
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-prometheus
```

For example : `https://github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter` in this following steps were mentioned

```
$ go get github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter
$ go build
$ ./redis_exporter <flags>
```

So I downloaded and installed Go and then used the above method to build and as a resultant I got redis_exporter.exe which I can use to monitor the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Prometheus exporters are distributed as binaries as part of a release, you can e.g. find Windows binaries for the redis_exporter [here](https://github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter/releases) and the elasticsearch_exporter [here](https://github.com/justwatchcom/elasticsearch_exporter/releases) - no need to build them yourselves.

However, the RabbitMQ Prometheus integration is not done via an exporter but by using a RabbitMQ plugin which will then expose metrics at port 15692 of the RabbitMQ process.

You can find more information on how to integrate RabbitMQ with Prometheus monitoring in the [documentation here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html).

Comment: they are the .exe files although it work but I have to run it every time before recording metrics. Is there any way by which I can simply enable the plugin like in case of rabbitmq version 3.8.

Comment: Some systems have native support for Prometheus and some need an exporter to extract metrics, it really depends on the system that you're trying to monitor.